# Which layout structure should I code to match my app design

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

For my new Flutter project I've done some research on layouts, however it still is a bit vague.
Here is the layout I'd like to create:

[image]

After some research and watching some videos, it seems this is the MaterialApp code:

```
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0E2E40),
          title: Text('City Discovery'),
          actions: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/logoicon.png',
              width: 35,
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            introSection,
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/barman.png',
              width: 600,
              height: 240,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            crimeSection,
            mysterySection,
            bottomSection,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But now defining the layout of the different Sections is quite hard.
From what I can tell, there should be:

1. ListView to make my page scrollable, which it should be
2. introSection: Container for XYZ with 2 rows for 2 text sections.
3. Image
4. crimeSection: Container for XYZ with 3 rows for 2 text sections and button. First text section divided into 2 colums for icon and text
5. mysterySection: Container for XYZ with 2 rows for 2 text sections. First text section divided into 2 columns for icon and text
6. bottomSection: Tabs? Although tabs only seem to be part of the appbar, so not sure what the alternative is

The closest example I could find, however changing the code doesn't get me anywhere:
https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/examples/layout/lakes/step6/lib/main.dart

For some reason containers can only have 1 child, so that probably means I need a row in my container which then has children  which then has 2 childs for both text sections? Incredibly hard to code some simple UI.

If someone can help me with the code for the introSection and the bottomSection, I can probably work out the rest myself.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create components folder for reusable widgets, as buttons, logos, text, etc.
If you have a widget that does not used in other components, you can separate it in the same file but use underscore, to make this widget private (It will be visible only inside this file). All that will make your code more readable.

About bottom tabs.

If you want to use it as bottom tabs, you can put it in `bottomNavigationBar` parameter of Scaffold widget. If you need to use in inside the `ListView`, it possible but you need to pass the exact height of the tab, because `TabView` trying to expand as much as possible, same as `ListView`.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LayoutExample(),
    );
  }
}

class LayoutExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _BottomNavigationBar(),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          _IntroSection(),
          Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 200),
          _CrimeSection(),
          _MysterySection()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _IntroSection extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Intro text1'),
          Text('Intro text2')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CrimeSection extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
      ),
      height: 200,
      child: Text('CrimeSection'),
    );
  }
}

class _MysterySection extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
      ),
      height: 200,
      child: Text('MysterySection'),
    );
  }
}

class _BottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```